# LINQ query using Contains and conditional logic

Tags: linq

I have 4 textboxes that are used for searching registered users.

Lastname, Firstname, SSN, County

I'm trying to make my LINQ query so that all 4 values are in my WHERE clause and the results drilldown each time the user enters data in another textbox.  The query needs to be able to handle empty string or ""

For example, there are 500 registered users. The user enters Smith in the LastName textbox and of the 500, there are 20 Smith users.

Now the user enters Smith for LastName and John for FirstName.  The query returns 5 Smith, John of the 500.

Now the user enters Smith for LastName and John for FirstName and Fulton for County.  The query returns 1 user.

How can I modify this query to drilldown when the end user searches for a registered user?

```
var query = _context.User
            .Where(r => r.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(lastname.ToUpper())
                || r.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(FirstName.ToUpper())
                || r.County.ToUpper().Contains(County.ToUpper())
                || r.SSN.ToUpper().Contains(SSN.ToUpper()));


var results = query
            .OrderBy(x => x.LastName)
            .Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your ORs to ANDs and only include the check if there is a value:

```
var query = _context.User
        .Where(r => 
               (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastname) || r.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(lastname.ToUpper())))
            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName) || r.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(FirstName.ToUpper()))
            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(County) || r.County.ToUpper().Contains(County.ToUpper()))
            && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SSN) || r.SSN.ToUpper().Contains(SSN.ToUpper()))
         );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query,

```
var query = _context.User
            .Where(r => (r.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(lastname.ToUpper()) && lastname!=null)
                || (r.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(FirstName.ToUpper()) && FirstName!=null)
                || (r.County.ToUpper().Contains(County.ToUpper()) && County != null)
                || (r.SSN.ToUpper().Contains(SSN.ToUpper()) && SSN!=null));
```